# Issue while converting string to DateTime using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am converting string dataframe to datetime using pyspark,
here is my input,

```
+--------------+
|        col1  |
+--------------+
|18300031121994|
|18300031122018|
|12324031012020|
|19590031052020|
|19590030062020|
+--------------+
```

Expected output,

```
col1
1994-12-31 18:30:00
2018-12-31 18:30:00
2020-01-31 12:32:40
2020-05-31 19:59:00
2020-06-30 19:59:00
```

here is my snippet,

```
df.select(col("col1"),to_date(col("col1"),"hhmmssMMddyyyy").alias("datetime")).show()
```

when I execute above code it gives the same output as input,
Please help where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct format. The correct format for the data you have provided is "hmmssddMMyyyy". Try this:

```
df.select(col("col1"),to_date(col("col1"),"hmmssddMMyyyy").alias("datetime")).show()
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: got this output: +--------------+-----------+
|        t_stdt|   datetime|
+--------------+-----------+
|18300031121994|       null|
|18300031122018|       null|
|12324031012020|12020-10-03|
|19590031052020|       null|
|19590030062020|       null|

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(df.timestamp_string, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: this is giving error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timestamp_string'